# thickbox content not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

I have created one page, which is called from another one by using `window.open` method.

now, when i open thickbox from the newly opened window, it just display lightblack background but not the content of the thickbox.
my code is like:

i have included thickbox.js and thickbox.css

Here is my **HTML** Code

```
<a href='#' id='createProfileNo' onclick="return addVideoUseful(false);">No</a>

<div id="editrowContainer" style="display: none;">
    <div>
        <label>comment:</label>
        <textarea cols="20" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my **Javascript** Function

```
function addVideoUseful(isUseful)
{
   tb_show('title', '#TB_inline?keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=500&amp;width=600&amp;modal=true&amp;inlineId=editrowContainer')
}
```

Please give me your valuable suggestions.......

Answer (score 0):

You mean by this div below!!

```
<div id="editrowContainer" style="display: none;">
```

if yes, then remove this style from that div `style="display: none;"`

That make your div not show anything within that div..

I hope this will help, :)